# Need information about working with Geoserver and Geojson

Tags: geoserver, geojson

I want to edit my country map so I first added [Geoserver](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Welcome) but I can't edit this map. I want to show openlayers using [Geojson](http://www.geojson.org/) but for some reason I can't edit this either.

How i can edit this map? The following is my code with geoserver link:

```
<script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="width:100%; height:100%" id="map"></div>
  <script defer="defer" type="text/javascript">
    var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
    var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
        "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0", {layers: 'basic'} );
    map.zoomToMaxExtent();
   new OpenLayers.Map("map");
    var dm_wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
    "OpenLayers WMS",
    "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?",
{
    layers: "trgm:iller",
    format: "image/png"
},
{
    isBaseLayer: false
}
                                        );
    map.addLayers([wms, dm_wms]);
    map.zoomToMaxExtent();
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To edit map data in geoserver, you need to use WFS Service.
Then using OpenLayers, you can set the layer editable.

see [OpenLayers example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wfs-protocol-transactions.html)